# Changing the Position of clicked item in RecyclerView on scroll

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

On click of button when I'm scrolling the view, it changes the
 position of that clicked button. On every scroll it's showing different
 position.

```
  public class ProductAdapter extends
            RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {
     Context ctx;
     ArrayList<ProductDetail> productList;

     public ProductAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<ProductDetail> productList) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.productList = productList;
     }

     @Override
     public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
     }

     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductViewHolder vHolder, int pos) {

        vHolder.txt_prod_name.setText(productList.get(pos).getProduct_desc());

        vHolder.btn_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vHolder.lyt_prod_qty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vHolder.btn_add.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
     }

     @Override
     public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int arg1) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.activity_recycler_search_item, null);
        ProductViewHolder viewHolder = new ProductViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;

     }
     public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txt_prod_name;
        TextView txt_delivery_type;
        TextView txt_prod_mrp;
        Spinner spn_prod_qty;
        LinearLayout list_lyt, lyt_prod_qty;
        Button btn_add;

        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txt_prod_name = (TextView) itemView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_prod_name);
            txt_delivery_type = (TextView) itemView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_delivery_type);
            txt_prod_mrp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_prod_mrp);
            btn_add = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        lyt_prod_qty = (LinearLayout) itemView
                .findViewById(R.id.lyt_prod_qty);
            }
        }
     }
```

On click of `Button` when I'mm scrolling the view, it changes the position of that clicked button. On every scroll it's showing different
position. Where should I out my click logic or should refresh the adapter every time?

Answer (score 0):

In your `ProductDetail` modal class add a member `boolean isButtonClicked;` and add its getter and setter as well. Then make following changes in your `onBindViewHolder` method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductViewHolder vHolder, int pos) {

  final ProductDetail productDetail = productList.get(pos);

  vHolder.txt_prod_name.setText(productDetail.getProduct_desc());

  if(productDetail.isButtonClicked()){
  vHolder.lyt_prod_qty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          vHolder.btn_add.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  } else {
   vHolder.lyt_prod_qty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          vHolder.btn_add.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }

  vHolder.btn_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          vHolder.lyt_prod_qty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          vHolder.btn_add.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          productDetail.setIsButtonClicked(true);
      }
  });
}
```